# Graphviz: Layout multiple clusters

Tags: graphviz, dot

```
digraph G {
  rankdir=LR;
  subgraph cluster_one {
    one_x -> one_y -> one_z;
  }
  subgraph cluster_two {
    two_x -> two_y;
  }
  subgraph cluster_three {
    three_x -> three_y;
  }
}
```

[image]

1. The order of the clusters is reversed. They should be in the order they appear in the source file.
2. I want all clusters to be of the same width (determined by the largest sub-graph) and aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The order of the clusters is reversed. They should be in the order they appear in the source file.

The following code should work:

```
digraph G {
  rankdir=LR;
  subgraph cluster_one {
    shape=rect;
    one_x -> one_y -> one_z;
  }
  subgraph cluster_two {
    two_x -> two_y;
  }
  subgraph cluster_three {
    three_x -> three_y;
  }
  one_x->two_y[style=invis];
  two_x->three_y[style=invis];
}
```

> I want all clusters to be of the same width (determined by the largest sub-graph) and aligned.

I have found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343955/how-do-i-get-graphviz-to-generate-fixed-sized-subgraphs). It is a bad solution, but I can't give a better one.